# Is Amazon SQS the right choice here? Rails performance issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backgroundworker, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I'm close to releasing a rails app with the common networking features (messaging, wall, etc.). I want to use some kind of background processing (most likely Bj) for off-loading tasks from the request/response cycle.

This would happen when users invite friends via email to join and for email notifications.

I'm not sure if I should just drop these invites and notifications in my Database, using a model and then just process it with a worker process every x minutes or if I should go for Amazon SQS, storing the messages and invites there and let my worker retrieve it from Amazon SQS for processing (sending the invites / notifications).

The Amazon approach would get load off my Database but I guess it is slower to retrieve messages from there.

What do you think?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your title states that you have a Rails performance issue, but do you know this for certain? From the rest of your question it sounds like you're trying to anticipate a possible future performance issue. The only way to deal sensibly with performance issues is to get your application into the wild and profile it. Doing so will give you empirical data as to what the real performance issues are.

Given that Amazon SQS isn't free and the fact that using it will almost certainly add complexity to your application, I would migrate to it **if** and **when** database load becomes a problem. Don't try to second guess problems before they arise, because you'll find that you'll likely face different problems when your app goes live, some of which you probably haven't considered.

The main point is that you've already decided to use background processing, which is the correct decision, given that any sort of processing that isn't instantaneous doesn't belong within the Rails' request/response cycle, as it blocks that Rails process. You can always scale with Amazon later if you need to.

Comment: I agree, that's probably the best. I just want to be prepared and I'm kind of a perfectionist so I try to anticipate as much as possible. But here I will just set up a nice background process and change the storage of the queque if needed. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Is your app hosted on Amazon EC2 already? I probably wouldn't move an existing app over to AWS just so I can use SQS, but if you're already using Amazon's infrastructure, SQS ia a great choice. You could certainly set up your own messaging system (such as RabbitMQ), but by going with SQS that's one less thing you have to worry about.

There are a lot of options to add background processing to Rails apps, such as [delayed_job](http://github.com/tobi/delayed_job) or [background_job](http://codeforpeople.rubyforge.org/svn/bj/trunk/README), but my personal favorite is [Workling](https://github.com/ascarter/workling). It gives you a nice abstraction layer that allows you to plug in different background runners without having to change the actual implementation of your jobs.

I maintain a [Workling fork that adds an SQS client](http://github.com/digitalhobbit/workling). There are some shortcomings (read the comments or [my blog post](http://www.digitalhobbit.com/2009/04/04/workling-and-amazon-sqs/) for more details), but overall it worked well for us at my last startup.

I've also used SQS for a separate Ruby (non-Rails) project and generally found it reliable and fast enough. Like James pointed out above, you can read up to 10 messages at once, so you'll definitely want to do that (my Workling SQS client does this and buffers the messages locally).

Answer (score 3):

I agree with John Topley that you don't want to over-complicate your application if you don't need to. That being said there are times when it is good to make this kind of decision early, do you anticipate high load from the beginning? Are you rolling this out to an existing user base or is it a public site that may or may not take off?

If you know you will need to handle a large amount of traffic from the beginning then this might be a good step. If you don't want to spend the money to use SQS take a look at some of the free queue solutions out there like RabbitMQ.

I currently push a couple million messages a month through SQS and it works pretty well. Make sure you plan for it being down or slow from time to time, so you would need to work in some retry facilities and exponential backoff. One of the nice things is that you can get 10 messages at a time which speeds up being able to work through the queue, you can use one request to get the 10 messages and process them 1 by 1.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon SQS is a fine service, except where the following things become important:

- Performance
- Legal
- Acknowledgments and Transactions
- Messaging Idioms Message Properties
- Security, Authenticity and Queue
- Permissions

If any of these things are important you need to look at a real enterprise MQ service such as StormMQ, RabbitMQ, or even onlinemq.com.

I found this blog series interesting as it compares Amazon SQS to StormMQ without holding any punches back:
http://blog.stormmq.com/2011/01/06/apples-and-oranges-performance/

Answer (score 0):

If you have issues with moving to EC2, You can use other services like onlinemq.com.